# level surface of a sphere

Tags: multivariable-calculus

consider we have a function $f(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ then the level surface of $f=1$ can be represented as $z=g(x,y)=\sqrt{1-x^2 - y^2}$ but I read in a book that this is true for $z\neq0$ why this is true only when $z\neq0$?

and another problem I have faced is that according to implicit function theorem there is a small interval such that $(x,y,g(x,y) = (x,y,z)$ why small interval why this isn't always true?

Comment: $g(x,y)$ is a function if for any $(x,y)$ pair there is a unique $z.$  If you have something like the surface of a spheres.  There are are two values on the sphere for any (x,y) pair, and it is easy  enough to always map to one hemisphere.  But if you are pick a point near the equator, then $g$ is only a function for constrained values of $x,y.$

Comment: @DougM can you explain more please.

Comment: for all $z=Z_0$ $x,y$ are constrained because $x^2+y^2$ should be $1-z^2$

Comment: @DougM please help me